# Publisher Action that Posts to Chatter

Tags: chatter, permissions, profile, publisher-action

I have a Publisher Action that posts to chatter on the Lead Object. This works fine when I am the System Admin however, I want this to work in a Community. Right now after the Community User clicks submit the post does not show up on the feed.

I believe that this is a profile issue. What permissions would I have to give the Community User to be able to post on the Chatter Feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the NetworkID on your ChatterPost for it to show up in the community. Posts are scoped according to this.

Try querying the CommunityID.